# Align text under picture, in relation to picture width

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS to try to align 2 pictures side by side with some text underneath each picture. I'm trying to make it so that the text under the picture justifies to the width of the picture, no matter what the size of the picture. But what I get as a result is the two blocks of text overlapping. For example, I want it to look like:

```
****************       ***************
* Image        *       *    Image    *
*              *       *             *
****************       ***************
Lorem ipsum dolor       Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet,               sit amet,
consectetuer            consectetuer
adipiscing              adipiscing
elit, sed diam          elit, sed diam
```

But I can't get the text under the image to justify, instead, they overlap. I also want it to come right before the footer (last element on the page before the footer), but the footer is overlapping some of the text as well. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="flower1small.jpg" alt="flower">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
           </div>

           <div class="image">
            <img src="flower1small.jpg" alt="flower">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
           </div>
         </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container{
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 10%;

}

.img {
  width:800px;

  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position: absolute;

 }
  .image {
  width:800px;

  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position: relative;

 }


div.img p{
    text-align: justify;
    display: block;
    width:800px;


}

.bottom{
  padding: 15px;
}

footer{
    background: #660000;
    position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
    width: 85%;
    height:100px;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;           
}

footer a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;

}

footer label{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;

}
```

What can I do to make it align properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a link to the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Fr35K/ The fiddle doesn't show the footer overlapping some of the text. But when I run the project in my browser, the footer overlaps the text. I tested it with Chrome, and the latest version of IE.

Comment: First off, they're set to 800px wide, so your screen would have to be 1600px wide before they could possibly sit next to each other. If that's correct, take off the absolute positioning and set the .img class to float:left

Comment: Updated the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr35K/2/)

Comment: Thank you everyone, for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this: [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr35K/1/) ?

You would have to set a max-width for the `.img` elements. I used an example of a max-width of 250px and images with a width of 200px. Also you need to float them and apply a clearfix, so that the footer is positioned correctly. The footer needs to get rid of `position: absolute`.

That the whole `.img` element just uses the width of the picture for the text is not possible without javascript, so you would have to set the width via CSS.

```
.container{
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 10%;
display: block;
}

.img {
  max-width:250px;  
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5%;
 }

.img img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.img p{
    text-align: justify;
    width:250px;
    display: block;
}

.bottom{
  padding: 15px;
}

footer{
    background: #660000;
    width: 85%;
    height:100px;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;           
}

footer a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;

}

footer label{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;

}

.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Comment: I learned something new, works like a charm. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Since both of these elements are within a container.  You could easily set the percentage of the containers child elements to the same percentage.  This way the image and the paragraph will always be the same width, no matter what your container size may be.

```
EX:
.image img, .image p { width: 90% }
```