# Float image to bottom after text

Tags: css, css-float

I have a div containing a floating image and a flanked text. If image is floated to left text is flanked right, if image is floated to right text is flanked left. To display everything fine I've put the `img` element before the text and used the `+` selector in CSS to give a proper margin to text (see code below).

For small screens, I would like to display text and image as blocks (100% width), with image placed below text. I've tried to use absolute positioning as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311990/how-do-i-get-a-div-to-float-to-the-bottom-of-its-container), but it didn't work: image is always displayed above. How can I accomplish my goal? Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="sectionimage left" src="image.jpg" />
    <div class="sectiontext"> <p>Some text.</p> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.sectionimage { /* must always be before text, even if floated right */
    vertical-align:bottom; 
    max-width:400px;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}

.left + .sectiontext {
    margin-left:500px; /* left margin for text after a "left" image */
}

.right + .sectiontext {
    margin-right:500px; /* right margin for text after a "right" image */
}

/* images and text displayed as blocks */
@media only screen and (max-width:950px) 
{
    .sectionimage, .sectiontext {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }

    .sectionimage {
        float:none;
    }

    .sectiontext {
        margin:0px !important;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/N57dL/)

Comment: Share a fiddle please.

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253856/align-text-under-picture-in-relation-to-picture-width

Comment: If only I could put `img` after text in HTML, everything would be fine. But the problem in that case would become: how can I select the text before `img` in CSS to give it a margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the below work for you?

## [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/U3dsx/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sectiontext left">
        <p>Some text.</p>
    </div>
    <img class="sectionimage" src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.sectionimage {
    /* must always be before text, even if floated right */
    vertical-align:bottom;
    max-width:400px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
.left {
    margin-right:500px;
}
.right {
    margin-left:500px;
}
/* images and text displayed as blocks */
 @media only screen and (max-width:950px) {
    .sectionimage, .sectiontext {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }
    .sectionimage {
        float:none;
    }
    .sectiontext {
        margin:0px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way I've found, hope it can be a nice alternative.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sectiontext right">
        <p>Some text.</p>
    </div>
    <img class="sectionimage" src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.sectionimage { 
    max-width:300px;
}

.left {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc(100% - 350px);
}

.right {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc(100% - 350px);
}

/* text displayed as block */
@media only screen and (max-width:500px) 
{
    .sectiontext,.sectionimage {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Here's the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXxnH/1/). Hope it helps someone.